# How to execute a bat file on remote server?

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have two physical machine. The first machine want to execute a bat file on the second machine. I create a share location on the second server and tried to run it from the first machine and it does not work. The bat file can run on the local machine properly.

This is an example of code inside the bat file. It is just a bat to create file.

```
echo. 2>EmptyFile.txt
```

This is the code that I use to execute bat file.

```
private static void ExecuteBatFile()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Security.SecureString ssPassword = new System.Security.SecureString();

    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"\\my_remote_server\my_bat.bat";
    proc.StartInfo.Domain = "my_domain";
    proc.StartInfo.UserName = "my_username";

    Console.Write("Enter your password: ");
    string password = Console.ReadLine();

    for (int x = 0; x < password.Length; x++)
    {
        ssPassword.AppendChar(password[x]);
    }

    proc.StartInfo.Password = ssPassword;
    proc.Start();
}
```

I want to know how can I run bat file on remote server?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31113/Create-a-Remote-Process-using-WMI-in-C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute commands on remote machines using [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553). I use it to execute batch files and pass parameters to them.

Comment: where do we need to install psexec ? on the server where files is present physically or on the server where we run the code to send the command ?

Comment: "Just copy PsExec onto your executable path. " -> where you run the code

Answer (score 2):

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "psexec \\my_remote_server -u my_username -p " & password & " my_bat.bat"
```

Or, if you need to specify the domain:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "psexec \\my_remote_server -u my_domain\my_username -p " & password & " my_bat.bat"
```

`psexec` is the only way **I** know how to execute a program on a remote computer.

Comment: where do we need to install psexec ? on the server where files is present physically or on the server where we run the code to send the command ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done from command prompt or bat file

```
wmic /node:MachineName> process call create "cmd.exe c:\Test\Test.bat"
```

For help type:

```
wmic /?
```

Comment: Looks like wmic is deprecated...