# how to run a batch file on a remote server

Tags: batch-file, remote-desktop

We have a remote windows server named hyperion.
It has a batch file to kill all the task and shut it down say abc.exe.
I want to write a script which will run this abc.exe from my VM . 
Note : I have to provide username and password to log into the hyperion server.

will PSEXEC/ help. If yes can someone give me the exact script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a bat file on remote server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668518/how-to-execute-a-bat-file-on-remote-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can use PsExec or WMI to do it. Here is a VBScript using WMI that will do it.

```
    strComputer = "RemoteServ"
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Set objWMIService = GetObject _
    ("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
    intReturn = objWMIService.Create("Executable.exe", Null, Null, intProcessID)
    if intReturn = 0 then
        wscript.echo "Program successfully launched"
    else 
        wscript.echo "There was a problem launching program"
    end if
    wscript.quit
```

Comment: Thank you matt. i understood most of it, can you please specify what is the intProcessId ??

Comment: Do i need to provide that ??

Comment: No. IntProcessID is the process id of the program you run on the remote server. You don't provide it.