# Execute .bat file on server F-drive from code behind

Tags: c#, code-behind

I have a .bat file on the servers F-drive which I wanna execute. The .bat file itself are calling another server and execute a .exe file. When I go in to the server and manually execute .bat it works fine. Now I wanna execute the .bat from C#.

I have tried several things.

## 1

```
ManagementClass management = new ManagementClass("Win32_Process");
    var inParams = mprocess.GetMethodParameters("Create");
    inParams["CommandLine"] = @"F:\Sysutv\Utils\StartnotepadTEST.bat";
    inParams["CurrentDirectory"] = @"F:\Sysutv\Utils\";
    mprocess.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
```

## 2

```
Process.Start(@"F:\Sysutv\Utils\StartnotepadTEST.bat");
```

## 3

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"/c start F:\Sysutv\Utils\StartnotepadTEST.bat");
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"F:\Sysutv\Utils\StartnotepadTEST.bat");
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\test\test.bat");
    processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    Process p = Process.Start(processInfo);
```

This is not working. How can I start that file that is on the server (from the server)?

The .bat file:

```
start F:\Sysutv\Utils\psexec.exe \\serverName -u login -p password -i C:\Windows\notepad.exe
```

Comment: Why it is not working ? are you getting an error ? Exception ?

Comment: If the file is on C-Drive then why you are accessing path on `F:` F Drive

Comment: C-drive of server or F, as in your path?

Comment: Sorry, it's the F-drive. No exceptions...

Comment: is it worth trying     Process.Start(@"\\servername\Sysutv\Utils\StartnotepadTEST.bat");

Comment: I am getting an error "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform." when I tried this  Process.Start(@"D:\123.bat");. Isnt it coz of a .bat file??

Comment: @krillezzz: Are you after [How to execute a bat file on remote server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668518/how-to-execute-a-bat-file-on-remote-server)

Comment: Can try. But dont I need the F: ? the server has more drives

Comment: @huMptyduMpty No. I'm trying to execute bat file on same server

Comment: Restart from the first comment. _Is Not Working_ is the most useless phrase that you could say in this site. Please tell us the error message that you get.

Comment: There is one problem though, when I run it manually on the server I need to press "Ok" when this window-administrator popup comes up...

Comment: How does "code-behind" even matter here?

Comment: @crashmstr why shouldn't it? It is triggered on button click

Comment: @krillezzz but is there anything here that specifically makes that tag useful and important? Or could the same code be used exactly the same in a console app?

Comment: Are you trying to run from a windows program or from an asp.net website ("code behind"). A program runs as "you", a website runs as a different user that doesn't know about any "F: drive", and probably can't access your network.

Comment: @crashmstr Because it's called from code-behind?

Comment: @HansKesting I'm trying to run this from a asp.net website (code-behind). I have a method before this code that make the user clicking the button set as "admin" so thats not the problem. I think the problem is that it can't find the servers F:-drive